# MudTablePager does not show "All" when int.maxvalue is in PageSizeOptions

Tags: mudblazor

According to the MudTable documentation:

[MudTable](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#tablepager-customization)

> Specifying int.MaxValue in the PageSizeOptions will render as "All" in
> the Page Size dropdown.

On the documentation page it works, and doing a "Run" also shows "All" in the dropdown. In my own code aswell as in the latest MudBlazor Visual Studio template however it does not and just shows 2147483647.

```
<MudTable Items="forecasts" >
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.Date)">Date</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.TemperatureC)">Temp. (C)</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.TemperatureF)">Temp. (F)</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x=>x.Summary!)">Summary</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Date">@context.Date</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Temp. (C)">@context.TemperatureC</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Temp. (F)">@context.TemperatureF</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Summary">@context.Summary</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 100, int.MaxValue }" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What version of MudBlazor are you using? This feature was implemented in version 6.1.7 (https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/releases/tag/v6.1.7)

Answer (score 0):

I installed the most recent template a couple of days ago. Turns out this is based on version 6.0.13. After updating it to 6.2.2 it now works.